# Abrir aplicativo externo dentro do form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

eu tenho uma duvida, eu queria carregar um exe externo(exemplo: c:\dark.exe) dentro de uma picture box do tamanho da mesma, eu tentei o codigo abaixo mas não funciona( obs o form precisa trabalhar na pasta de destino). e mesmo que o dark.exe esteja aberto, ao clicar no button o form puxe ele para dentro

```
 Public Class Form1
        Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
        Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
        Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
        Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
        Dim proc As Process

        Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

            proc = Process.Start("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe")
            proc.WaitForInputIdle()
            SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Me.Panel1.Handle)
            SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
            Me.BringToFront()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Não há como você carregar um executável para rodar dentro de seu formulário ou qualquer dos controles - e isso, se houvesse um jeito, usaria TANTA API que temo não ser possível no .NET

O máximo que você pode fazer é tentar abrir o executável numa janela e tentar reposicionar esta janela nas mesmas coordenadas de seu aplicativo ou Picture.

Use "SetWindowPos" como descrito aqui:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx

Aqui voce pode ter um exemplo em C#:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos

ou algo assim como segue:

```
  Imports System.Collections.Generic
  Imports System.Linq
  Imports System.Text
  Imports System.Diagnostics
  Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
  Imports System.Threading

  Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim flash As New Process()
        flash.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        flash.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\FlashPlayer.exe"
        flash.Start()
        Thread.Sleep(100)

        Dim id As IntPtr = flash.MainWindowHandle
        Console.Write(id)
        Program.MoveWindow(flash.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, 500, 500, True)
    End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError := True)> _
Friend Shared Function MoveWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, X As Integer, Y As Integer, nWidth As Integer, nHeight As Integer, bRepaint As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function


   End Class
```